# Sorting numbers in a row on the BASH / Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ksh

There is a line:

```
00000000000000;000022233333;2;NONE;true;100,100,5,1,28;UNKNOWN
```

It is necessary to sort `100`,`100`,`5`,`1`,`28` numbers in descending order.

Example:

```
00000000000000;000022233333;2;NONE;true;100,100,28,5,1;UNKNOWN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this;

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line           
do   
beforeC=$(echo "$line" | cut -f-5 -d';')
sortcolumn=$(echo "$line" | awk -F ";" '{print $6}' | tr -t , "\n" | sort -r -n | xargs | sed 's/ /,/g') 
afterC=$(echo "$line" | cut -f7- -d';')
echo -e $beforeC";"$sortcolumn";"$afterC
done <file 


user@host:/tmp/test$ cat file 
00000000000000;000022233333;2;NONE;true;100,100,5,1,28;UNKNOWN
00000000000000;000022233333;2;NONE;true;99,100,5,1,28;UNKNOWN
00000000000000;000022233333;2;NONE;true;100,99,5,1,28;UNKNOWN
00000000000000;000022233333;2;NONE;true;100,100,4,1,28;UNKNOWN
00000000000000;000022233333;2;NONE;true;100,100,4,0,28;UNKNOWN
00000000000000;000022233333;2;NONE;true;100,100,4,1,27;UNKNOWN

user@host:/tmp/test$ ./sortAColumn.sh 
00000000000000;000022233333;2;NONE;true;100,100,28,5,1;UNKNOWN
00000000000000;000022233333;2;NONE;true;100,99,28,5,1;UNKNOWN
00000000000000;000022233333;2;NONE;true;100,99,28,5,1;UNKNOWN
00000000000000;000022233333;2;NONE;true;100,100,28,4,1;UNKNOWN
00000000000000;000022233333;2;NONE;true;100,100,28,4,0;UNKNOWN
00000000000000;000022233333;2;NONE;true;100,100,27,4,1;UNKNOWN
```